# Gtk+3 error: 'GLocalFile' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3

I am using following way to insert side bar in my file manager:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gio


def on_open_location(placessidebar, location, flags):
#        import pdb;
#        pdb.set_trace()
        location = placessidebar.get_location()

        print("Opened URI: %s" % (GLocalFile.get_uri(location)))


def create_side_bar():
    # side bar
    placessidebar = Gtk.PlacesSidebar()
    placessidebar.set_open_flags(Gtk.PlacesOpenFlags.NORMAL)
    placessidebar.connect("open-location", on_open_location)

    return placessidebar
```

But whenever I run this code:

```
NameError: name 'GLocalFile' is not defined
```

I tried debugging it and noticed following things:

```
location
<__gi__.GLocalFile object at 0x7f3ea42b5cf0 (GLocalFile at 0x1aaae40)>
```

`location` is a parameter that is of type `GLocalFile`, so seeing this I also tried `__gi__.GLocalFile` and as expected it gave:

```
NameError: name '__gi__' is not defined
```

By searching online I saw everyone is using the same code for side bar, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GLocalFile` is an internal-only class, so even though it shows up in debug messages you can't access it in Python.

(The `NameError: name 'GLocalFile' is not defined` makes sense, because there isn't anything in your program that imports that name.)

According to the [documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/PlacesSidebar.html#Gtk.PlacesSidebar.get_location), the return type of `Gtk.PlacesSidebar.get_location()` is `Gio.File`, so you can just call `location.get_uri()`.

Comment: sorry for being so late, I got busy during my exams and by mistake overlooked your answer. Thanks for helping me out :)